# Generics subclass behavior in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a query in below code.

When I declare list of animals it allows me to put Cat() and Dog() in it as they both are animal and satisfy IS A relation ship.

```
Class Cat extends Animal{}
Class Dog extends Animal{}

List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(new Dog());//Code works fine
list.add(new Cat());//Code works fine
```

Now here is my question if  `? extends` means accept anything that is subclass of Animal, then why is following code not compiling.

```
List<? extends Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(new Dog());//Compilation fails 
list.add(new Cat());//Compilation fails
```

Same question, why dog is not accepted here?

```
List<? extends Animal> dogs1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
dogs1.add(new Dog());//Compilation fails
```

Can some one explain this behavior?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, someone will flag it. Basically, your List could be of any subclass of Animal. If it were a List<Dog> you wouldn't be able to add cats and vice versa. Because Java can't tell what it is, it doesn't allow you to add anything to it

Comment: @Kayaman That is a weird "duplicate"

Comment: Mods-Please check valid duplicate....:( else don't mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable of type `List<? extends Animal>` can be assigned a `List<Animal>`, a `List<Cat>` or a `List<Dog>`. Some of these lists don't allow `Dog`s to be added to them, while others don't allow `Cat`s.

The compiler validates the correctness of the `list.add` statements based on the compile time type of the `list` variable, not based on the actual object assigned to it in runtime. Therefore both `list.add(new Dog());` and `list.add(new Cat());` are not accepted.

If you wish to be able to add both `Dog`s and `Cat`s, use a variable of type `List<Animal>`.

If you wish to only be able to add `Dog`s, use a variable of type `List<Dog>`.

Comment: @Eran- A variable of type List<Animal> will do the same thing , then why List<Animal> is working fine.

Comment: Because the type is known at compile time, so the compiler can do the validations

Comment: @ShowStopper A variable of type `List<Animal>` can't be assigned a `List<Dog>` or a `List<Cat>`. Therefore you can safely add to it both `Dog`s and `Cat`s.

Comment: @Eran- List<? extends Animal> listAnimal = new ArrayList<Animal>();
  List <Cat> listCat = listAnimal; this is also not valid in java

Comment: @Eran- You can not assign A variable of type List<? extends Animal> to a List<Animal>, a List<Cat> or a List<Dog>.  I just checked . Will you please check again

Comment: @ShowStopper I never said you can do that. I said you can assign a `List<Animal> to a `List<Animal> variable and a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Dog>` variable.

Comment: @ShowStopper `You can not assign A variable of type List<? extends Animal> to a List<Animal>, a List<Cat> or a List<Dog>`. I said the opposite - you can assign a `List<Cat>` to a `List<? extends Animal>` variable, not the other way.